# How to recover from academic burnout as an undergraduate student?

Tags: undergraduate, motivation

I am from Nepal. I am computer engineering student. We have 7 subjects per semester. We have options to take fewer courses exams per semester. But this is Nepal, graduating even a month later is not culturally accepted here, otherwise I would have decided to not take 1 or 2 exams fewer.

So that is not the option.

I study for may be around 3/4 hrs during class days and around 8 hrs during no class days i.e 1 month before exam. The rule for studying in engineering is 3x the lectures that you have. We have 25 hrs of lectures per week, so 75 hrs of study per week is the bare minimum to succeed, I don't do that much though...

I am an average student, I love studying computer engineering. I find it fun. I studied with my own nobody forced me to do it.

But always during exams, I get burnt out. I did well in my first exam as I studied 8 hrs for 3 days continuously. (We have 3 days exam gaps before each exam).

I get burnt out during only 1 exam or 2 exam at max. Not all. How do I recover quickly from burn out. Tommorow is my exam and I got burnt out the day before, I didn't know about stackexchange or else I would have asked previously (it didn't come to my mind)...I don't want this to repeat again. My exam tomorrow is gone. Of course I will pass as I have already completed the syllabus. But I won't get good marks like I expected. This happens a lot to me.

This is going to ruin my future. Due to this my net gpa will be extremely low. Which won't really show my true knowledge. I don't know who will take me in the future with such a low gpa. Every postgraduate program wants you to get higher gpa, every job always selects people with higher gpa and here I am losing gpa on subjects that I have already completed just because of burn out. I think my life is finished tbh...I have very little hope at this moment.

My medical conditions-:

I am taking medicine olanzapine and fludep. They don't have any side effects on me. But they help me a lot for my mental health issues. In the past it was even worse than this.

Comment: It seems like a heavy load. I was once in that situation and was able to drop a course to relieve it. Does your university have a counseling office that can help with such problems? They are fairly common.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the culture in Nepal, so this may be off the mark. But it seems there is external pressure on you to finish the coursework faster than required by the University system. It's perhaps worth keeping in mind that such external pressure can feel overwhelming in the moment, but sometimes turns out not to be so important five years later. It might be worth thinking about whether your job prospects will be better taking a few extra months or a year to get better grades at University, than finishing more quickly with a less good understanding.

Comment: @Andrew the thing is none of the students take classses off..All take 7 subjects per semester, so it is quite uncommon to take few classes. And my issue tbh isn't more classes, I just get burnt out studying. I had finished studying this subject already, all I needed was a revision to score 50/80, with what I have studied I will get 32/80 but that is just sad. AFAIK, opportunities will be better if I get better gpa rather than graduating fast.

Comment: My instinct is that comparing yourself to others ("none of the students take classes off") is exactly the kind of thing that *seems* important now, but turns out not to be in five years. What matters is whether you will be successful in your life. I would *guess* (again, with major caveats around cultural differences), that many employers would prefer to hire someone with a stronger background and gpa that took one extra year at school, than someone who finished "on time" but has a poor gpa. (I would rather work for such an employer!) Reducing workload is surely a way to help with burnout.

Comment: But I do agree with Buffy that seeking out counseling is a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks man, @Andrew This will help me decide. My common sense tells me having a good gpa will help me go further in life than graduating faster as I have heard most US college students graduation rate is <60%. I think I will take an extra year in school. But I am sure it is going to be unbearable as it is not culturally acceptable here to graduate late. It makes sense tho, as we don't have to work for studying and we are full time students. PS I was always a great student in the past and that puts up pressure.

Comment: But how come some students have no issue with this at all. While I agree most students study just to pass there are around 10 students out of 100 students who consistently score 80%+ even in these circumstances. How are they doing it tho?

Comment: I was a great student in high school and struggled a lot when I started college. I'm sure the details of my situation aren't transferrable, but I found (a) the environment to be very different and difficult to adjust to, (b) going from being a big fish in a small pond to just another fish in a huge pond to be very challenging, (c) the level of the work was higher than I was used to and I needed to put in more effort than I had before. Don't spend too much time comparing yourself to others, that way lies madness. Focus on what you can control.

Comment: Also I went to school in an era well before covid. I can only imagine that makes everything much harder.

Comment: It's better to drop a course than fail 3. I do think undergrad programs often try to cram too much in and do none of it well. Quality over quantity is better.